# Message size limit for Facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger, facebook-messenger

I am trying to implement a Facebook messenger bot. I have trouble with the bot replying with a response that contains large amount of words. Is there a limit to the number of words that can be used in a response?

P.S : It works fine otherwise

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [described in the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api#message), text message *must be UTF-8 and has a 2000 character limit*.

There are other restrictions [in template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#guidelines) for field title, subtitle & call-to-actions button.

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for

Comment: Now 2000 character limit

Answer (score 9):

Looks like, the limit has been updated to 2000 characters now.[image]

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api#request